# Retrieve data from a json object with square brackets enclosing the value of some object

Tags: java, json

I have a Jsonobject that contain some values that were an Arraylist before converting it to Jsonobject

```
[{"id":4,"name":"shirt","attributeName":["size"],"attributeValue":["6-7"],"attributeStock":["3"]}]
```

how can get attributeName & attributeValue & attributeStock  like an Arraylist

Answer (score -1):

I solve it by this code (jsonFavorites  is a String that contain several jsonobject same to that i post in the Question  [{},{},{}])

```
try
        {
            JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(jsonFavorites);
            for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject object=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                int id=object.getInt("id");
                String name=object.getString("name");
                JSONArray Namearray=object.getJSONArray("attributeName");
                JSONArray Valuearray=object.getJSONArray("attributevalue");
                JSONArray Stockarray=object.getJSONArray("attributeStock");


                ArrayList<String> attributeName=new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<String> attributevalue=new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<String> attributeStock=new ArrayList<>();

                for (intj=0; j<Namearray.length();j++)
                {
                    attributeName.add(Namearray.getString(j));
                    attributevalue.add(Valuearray.getString(j));
                    attributeStock.add(Stockarray.getString(j));

                }   
               }
             }catch (Exception e){}
```